# Compiler emits std::move() runtime call?

Tags: c++

Assuming the following code:

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

using std::cout;
using std::string;

void print(string && s)
{
    cout << s << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    string sso{"With SSO"};
    string no_sso{"This string is much too large to have SSO, much too large"};

    print(std::move(sso));
    print(std::move(no_sso));
}
```

Compiled with `g++ -g -Wall -Wpedantic -std=c++14 -o move_poc main.cpp` (the results are similar using g++/clang++ on msys2 and Ubuntu).

Looking at the ouput of `objdump -d -l -S move_poc`, we get this:

```
   print(std::move(sso));
c5f:    48 8d 45 a0             lea    -0x60(%rbp),%rax
c63:    48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
c66:    e8 05 01 00 00          callq  d70
_ZSt4moveIRNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEONSt16remove_referenceIT_E4typeEOS8_

c6b:    48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
c6e:    e8 47 ff ff ff          callq  bba 
_Z5printONSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
```

`c++filt` tells us the first mangled symbol is (edited for brevity)

```
std::remove_reference<...>::type&& std::move<...>(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)
```

It was my understanding that std::move() didn't generate anything at runtime, which I interpreted as "std::move() is a compile-time operation". Looking at the generated assembly above, it seems I got it wrong.

Is std::move() supposed to do anything at runtime? Or, since compiling with -O2 gets rid of this call, is this just a result of compiling without optimization?

Comment: "[I]s this just a result of compiling without optimization?" Yes.

Comment: You compiled for debugging ... this will let you step into the function call in the debugger

Comment: @Justin: The comments section is not for providing answers to the question. You know this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It was my understanding that std::move() didn't generate anything at runtime, which I interpreted as "std::move() is a compile-time operation". Looking at the generated assembly above, it seems I got it wrong.

No, you got it right, but it's still a function call, and with optimisations turned off your compiler deliberately doesn't remove otherwise "pointless" calls. This is to aid in debugging.

It's also why "optimisations turned off" is a poor description for this compilation mode; it's more like "make the target code resemble the original source code a lot more than it actually needs to". The true meaning of "optimisations turned on" is "do a proper job translating this abstract description of a program into something real that can be executed in a useful and efficient manner". Of course in the 15th Century a C program was sort of a step-by-step description of what you wanted the executing computer to do, and in that context plonking "optimisations" on top of the process makes some sense… but this hasn't been the case for a long time.

> Is std::move() supposed to do anything at runtime?

No, its effect is purely "compile-time" in the sense that it evaluates to the expression you gave it but with a different value category (a purely "compile-time" concept). It doesn't actually "do" anything.

> Or, since compiling with -O2 gets rid of this call, is this just a result of compiling without optimization?

Yes.